# Getting values from XML in Android (API Level 3)

Tags: android, xml, regex, xpath

I have a string that contains a xml structure and there are two pieces of data in separate tags that I am after.

xpath has been added since API level 8, and with me being stuck with API level 3 (old phone for you ;-)) I need a way to get the data.

Would using a regular expression commit a huge sin? ;-)  The xml isn't that big...

Looking for some guidance on what to.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It might help if you added the XML and what you were hoping to achieve with it, but you should be able to parse the XML string using `DocumentBuilder`, this will return a `Document` and with that you should be able to call `getElementsByTagName()`